# the behavior of a break in an __extension__ for g++ is not the same for gcc version 12.2.0 and gcc version 5.4.0

Tags: c++, gcc

**The context** (bypass it if you don't care) :

I am compiling qt 4.8.7 on my Raspberry Pi 5 64b under Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) and I have problems including about the translation to produce the qm file from the ts file

I discover the problem concerns the Qt foreach which stops after the first element, and that because of a *break* in an *__extension __* having (for me) a strange behavior.

**The problem** :

with that code reproducing the problem

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
    for (int j = i;; __extension__ ({break;}))
      std::cout << j << std::endl;
}
```

On my old ubuntu 16.04 with gcc version 5.4.0 20160609, the execution prints the number 0 up to 4.

But on my raspberry pi5 with gcc version 12.2.0 (Debian 12.2.0-14) the execution only writes 0, and if I replace the *break* by a *continue* the execution writes 0 up to 4.
The *break/continue* concerns the outer loop, and this is visible if I try to compile :

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for (int j = 1;; __extension__ ({break;}))
      std::cout << j << std::endl;
}
```

producing *error: break statement not within loop or switch*

Is the behavior of *__extension __* changed or is that a (known ?) bug ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html:

> A `break` or `continue` statement inside of a statement expression used in `while`, `do` or `for` loop or `switch` statement condition or `for` statement init or increment expressions jumps to an outer loop or switch statement if any (otherwise it is an error), rather than to the loop or `switch` statement in whose condition or init or increment expression it appears.

So the behaviour you see on 12.2.0 (only printing `0`, the `break` breaking the outer loop) is the intended behaviour.

There was a bug before GCC 9 (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44715) where in C++ mode, the `break` would apply to the inner loop and in C mode, the `break` would apply to the outer loop. So if you wish to support GCC 5.4.0, you cannot use `break` in statement expressions.

And anyways, this is confusing to read. You would rather rewrite your code so your `break` can be in the body of the loop rather than in the increment expression.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In fact to replace the break by a continue does the job. In the original definition it is not possible to move the break because all is in a macro Q_FOREACH , and the body is not accessible. That new behavior is very strange, it is confusing, and that breaks the compatibility with older releases. Anyway this is practicle

Comment: @bruno Then `Q_FOREACH` is broken in GCC 9+. You might have an outdated QT installation but from what I'm reading `Q_FOREACH` is no longer used

Comment: @Ar yes qt 4.8.7 is outdated, but I want to compile BoUML using it under the raspberry pi 64b under the recent Debian. In fact I was able to do it yesterday, but using old generated files for translation and "uic" files. WIth an own Q_FOREACH definition the problem disapears.

Comment: I remove what I said, the current behavior is the right one and yes it was a bug before, we are not in a for etc until we are not in its body, this is logical